# PyTorch: Batch size=1 but model gives 2 outputs

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Here is some part of my PyTorch code:

```
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset = test_loader_hibiscus, batch_size = 1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

test_losses = []
y_pred_list = []
feat_list = []
with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0.0
    if expe_temoin == False :
        for test_dwi,test_adc,test_tmax,test_cbf,test_cbv,test_label in test_loader :
            test_dwi = test_dwi.to(device)
            test_adc = test_adc.to(device)
            test_tmax = test_tmax.to(device)
            test_cbf = test_cbf.to(device)
            test_cbv = test_cbv.to(device)

            in_imgs = torch.cat((train_dwi,train_adc,train_tmax,train_cbf,train_cbv), dim=1)

            out_recon, my_feat = model(in_imgs)
            print("my_feat", my_feat[0].shape)
```

But it prints:

```
my_feat torch.Size([2, 512, 1, 24, 24])
```

Could someone please tell me why 2 (batch?) Thanks!

Hint: When I run with test data size: 26, its OK, when run with data size: 25, mess up the batch! Is there something about being odd and even?!

Here is the Unet 3d model for 3D reconstruction and segmentation:

```
class Abstract3DUNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, final_sigmoid, basic_module, f_maps=64, layer_order='gcr',
                 num_groups=8, num_levels=4, is_segmentation=True, testing=False,
                 conv_kernel_size=3, pool_kernel_size=2, conv_padding=1, **kwargs):
        super(Abstract3DUNet, self).__init__()

        self.testing = testing

        if isinstance(f_maps, int):
            f_maps = number_of_features_per_level(f_maps, num_levels=num_levels)

        assert isinstance(f_maps, list) or isinstance(f_maps, tuple)
        assert len(f_maps) > 1, "Required at least 2 levels in the U-Net"

        # create encoder path
        self.encoders = create_encoders(in_channels, f_maps, basic_module, conv_kernel_size, conv_padding, layer_order,
                                        num_groups, pool_kernel_size)

        # create decoder path
        self.decoders = create_decoders(f_maps, basic_module, conv_kernel_size, conv_padding, layer_order, num_groups,
                                        upsample=True)

        # in the last layer a 1×1 convolution reduces the number of output
        # channels to the number of labels
        self.final_conv = nn.Conv3d(f_maps[0], out_channels, 1)

        if is_segmentation:
            # semantic segmentation problem
            if final_sigmoid:
                self.final_activation = nn.Sigmoid()
            else:
                self.final_activation = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        else:
            # regression problem
            self.final_activation = None

    def forward(self, x):
        # encoder part
        encoders_features = []
        my_feat =[]
        for encoder in self.encoders:
            x = encoder(x)
            # reverse the encoder outputs to be aligned with the decoder
            encoders_features.insert(0, x)

        # remove the last encoder's output from the list
        # !!remember: it's the 1st in the list
        my_feat = encoders_features[0:]
        encoders_features = encoders_features[1:]

        # decoder part
        for decoder, encoder_features in zip(self.decoders, encoders_features):
            # pass the output from the corresponding encoder and the output
            # of the previous decoder
            x = decoder(encoder_features, x)

        x = self.final_conv(x)

        # apply final_activation (i.e. Sigmoid or Softmax) only during prediction. During training the network outputs
        # logits and it's up to the user to normalize it before visualising with tensorboard or computing validation metric
        if self.testing and self.final_activation is not None:
            x = self.final_activation(x)

        return x, my_feat


class UNet3D(Abstract3DUNet):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, final_sigmoid=True, f_maps=64, layer_order='gcr',
                 num_groups=8, num_levels=4, is_segmentation=True, conv_padding=1, **kwargs):
        super(UNet3D, self).__init__(in_channels=in_channels,
                                     out_channels=out_channels,
                                     final_sigmoid=final_sigmoid,
                                     basic_module=DoubleConv,
                                     f_maps=f_maps,
                                     layer_order=layer_order,
                                     num_groups=num_groups,
                                     num_levels=num_levels,
                                     is_segmentation=is_segmentation,
                                     conv_padding=conv_padding,
                                     **kwargs)
```

Comment: You need to post the code for model so we can see what it does

Comment: Added:
Hint: When I run with test data size: 26, its OK, when run with data size: 25, mess up the batch!

Comment: A "hint" is not useful. If you want help solving your problem, you need to provide all of the information necessary for someone to reproduce the error themselves

Comment: here you go!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My train batch size was 3! When I changed it into 2 or 4 the problem solved!